# how to force jboss to use hibernate-entitymanager.jar from WAR instead of Jboss_home directory

Tags: spring, maven, jboss

My problem is as follows I use in my WS app `Hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.6-FINAL` jar, JBOSS 4.2.3 have in his direction hibernate if i am not wrong 3.3.x which make conflict of versions. Don't redirect me to `ClassLoader` related articles of JBOSS i have read them, and put this in `JBOSS_HOME\server\default\deploy\management\console-mgr.sar\web-console.war\WEB-INF\jboss-web.xml`

```
<class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
 <loader-repository>
  pl.mycompany:archive=hibernate-entitymanager 
  <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config> 
 </loader-repository>
</class-loading>
```

can anyone give me a hint what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See article [ClassLoadingConfiguration](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/classloadingconfiguration):

They mention about **unique-archive-name**

---

For jboss-service.xml:

```
<server>
   <loader-repository>
      com.example:archive=unique-archive-name
      <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
   </loader-repository>
```

...

The isolated EAR or WAR repository will load its libraries in this order:

```
WEB-INF/lib (for WARs)

libraries in server/default/lib

tomcat-libraries in server/default/deploy/jbossweb-tomcat50.sar (jboss-3.2.6).
```

The libraries in server/default/lib get mixed together with jbossweb-tomcat50.sar in no specific order (for details look into the loader-repository in the JMX-console).

---

Second solution: Remove hibernate classes from jboss (move to endorsed).